# Using path prefix in Android

Tags: android, url

I have urls like this:

- `https://a.com/myapp/test.html`
- `https://c.com/myapp/test1.html`

The host of the url can change but the path prefix will remain constant like **myapp** as it is the **context root** of my web app.

So i want my filter to only recognize with the schemes of `https` and `http` and when the path prefix is **myapp**. I did that but my application is responding to all the urls which are having the schemes.

Will the path prefix filter won't work if host is not mentioned in the `manifest.xml` ?

Any other ideas how i can i write my intent filter for my scenario ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead by putting host="*" and then path prefixing.

This way all the hosts will be matched but will be filtered out by the path values.

Let me know if this is the correct way or if there could be some better way ?

cheers,
Saurav

Comment: Hi saurav, This is not working lollipop can you help how get all host names.